# How can I add a second geom_point in ggplot based on a subset if sometimes that subset is purposefully empty?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code that works pretty well. Basically what it does is run through all the states and chambers of that state to make a plot of each:

```
lapply(unique(finaldat$st), function(s){
  chambs <- unique(finaldat$chamber[finaldat$st == s])
  p <- list(NULL)
  for(c in 1:length(chambs)){
    p[[c]] <- finaldat %>% filter(st == s & chamber == chambs[c]) %>%

      ggplot(aes(x = average, y = score, col = color))+
      geom_point(aes(size= Total,alpha = 0.5)) +
      stat_smooth(method = "lm") + 
      geom_point(data=subset(finaldat,st==s & chamber == chambs[c] & highlight>0),aes(col="yellow")) +
      ggtitle(paste(s,chambs[c],year)) + 
      scale_size(range = c(.5,3.5)) + 
      scale_color_manual(labels = c("1","2","3"), 
                         values = c("blue","red","yellow"))

    filename = filename <- paste(s,chambs[c],year)
    ggsave(paste("Plots/",filename,".png"), width = 10, height = 7)
  }     
  return(p)
})
```

Works fine for the first few states but I run into issues with the second `geom_point` line which basically serves as a way to highlight certain people in yellow:

```
... + geom_point(data=subset(finaldat,st==s & chamber == chambs[c] & highlight>0),aes(col="yellow")) + ...
```

Because it's a subset of the data frame, there are certain iterations of this data where this subset turns up an empty dataframe because the sometimes no one purposefully has values higher than zero in `highlight` variable -- hence I get an error and it stops the loop. But I'm trying to figure out a way where if I get an error due to that subset being empty it just ignores that one line. But I couldn't figure out any good `ifelse` statements or anything to make that happen.

Here's an example of what the data looks like:

```
st    chamber    average    score    color    Total    highlight 
AK    Upper      .64        54       1        849      1
AK    Upper      .84        91       1        743      0
AK    Upper      .35        14       2        442      0
AK    Upper      .95        54       1        641      4
AK    Lower      .64        54       1        849      0
AK    Lower      .84        91       1        743      0
AK    Lower      .35        14       2        442      0
AK    Lower      .95        54       1        641      0
```

Etc throughout all the states/chambers -- but in this example, the highlight would work for AK Upper but not AK Lower. So basically when the loop gets to AK Lower I just need it to ignore that second `geom_point` because the empty subset will cause it to error. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just stop the plot composition chain before the `geom_point` in question, do a size test, add it if it's OK to the plot object then add the rest to the plot object either way? there's no good reason to not break the composition chain.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks! Would you mind sharing the changes you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lapply(unique(finaldat$st), function(s){
  chambs <- unique(finaldat$chamber[finaldat$st == s])
  p <- list(NULL)
  for(c in 1:length(chambs)){
    p[[c]] <- finaldat %>% filter(st == s & chamber == chambs[c]) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = average, y = score, col = color))+
      geom_point(aes(size= Total,alpha = 0.5)) +
      stat_smooth(method = "lm") -> gg

    if (YOUR TEST HERE) {
      gg <- gg + geom_point(data=subset(finaldat,st==s & chamber == chambs[c] & highlight>0),aes(col="yellow")) +
    }

    gg +
      ggtitle(paste(s,chambs[c],year)) + 
      scale_size(range = c(.5,3.5)) + 
      scale_color_manual(labels = c("1","2","3"), 
                         values = c("blue","red","yellow"))

    filename = filename <- paste(s,chambs[c],year)
    ggsave(paste("Plots/",filename,".png"), width = 10, height = 7)
  }     
  return(p)
})
```